# Magento 2: how to create your own custom cache type?

Tags: magento2, module, cache, magento-2.0, full-page-cache

In Magento 1, it was possible to create your own cache type by declaring the following in your `config.xml`:

```
<global>
    <cache>
        <types>
            <custom translate="label,description" module="module">
                <label>Custom Cache</label>
                <description>This is my custom cacge</description>
                <tags>CUSTOM_CACHE_TAG</tags>
            </custom >
        </types>
    </cache>
</global>
```

It will result in a new cache type added to the backend under **System > Cache Management** and thus, it will add the ability to flush cache related to the `CUSTOM_CACHE_TAG` cache tag.

Is that possible in M2 and how to achieve it ?

Comment: For a sample implementation of the accepted answer see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150074/using-magento-2-custom-cache-in-custom-module

Comment: For a sample implementation of the accepted answer see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150074/using-magento-2-custom-cache-in-custom-module

Comment: You can follow this link to create custom cache in magento 2 https://tagvibe.com/magento2-cache/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is below some basic structure for create custom cache type,

create one module with,

**`app/code/Vendor/Cachetype/etc/cache.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
    <type name="custom_cache" translate="label,description" instance="Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache\Type">
        <label>Custom Cache type</label>
        <description>Custom cache description.</description>
    </type>
</config>
```

**`app/code/Vendor/Cachetype/i18n/en_US.csv`**

```
"Custom cache description.","Custom cache description."
"cachetype","Cache type"
```

**`app/code/Vendor/Cachetype/Model/Cache/Type.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache;

/**
 * System / Cache Management / Cache type "Custom Cache Tag"
 */
class Type extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{
    /**
     * Cache type code unique among all cache types
     */
    const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'custom_cache_tag';

    /**
     * Cache tag used to distinguish the cache type from all other cache
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'CUSTOM_CACHE_TAG';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool)
    {
        parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell how to utilize cache. I mean how to add, delete, check cache items.

Comment: if somebody know how to store and get cache data, would be great. Please

Comment: @ArshadHussain https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150074/using-magento-2-custom-cache-in-custom-module

Answer (score 2):

Would like to edit Rakesh accepted comment, but was rejected....

Anyway here some modifications, additional info to the good answer from Rakesh:

The cache.xml needs to be modfied a little:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
<type name="custom_cache_tag" translate="label,description" instance="Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache\Type">
        <label>Custom Cache type</label>
        <description>Custom cache description.</description>
    </type>
 </config>
```

So the the name must match the cache_tag.

How to use it, look here: [Using Magento 2 custom cache in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150074/using-magento-2-custom-cache-in-custom-module)

To use the data (after being cached) you have to unserialize it:

```
$data = unserialize($this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey));
```

Comment: how to Clear custom cache from cache management Magento 1 ?