# Using Magento 2 custom cache in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, cache

@Rakesh explains how to add custom cache in Magento 2 [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/magento-2-how-to-create-your-own-custom-cache-type).

My question is how to actually work with my custom cache in Magento 2?

In Magento 1 you would do something like:

```
$cacheId = 'example_id';
$cacheTag = 'block_html';
//check if our example_id cache contains any data - load() method will return false if cache is empty
if (($data_to_be_cached = Mage::app()->getCache()->load($cacheId))) {
    //if cache was found then unserialize it and assign to our variable
    $data_to_be_cached = unserialize($data_to_be_cached);
} else {
    //if not then normally assign data to the variable
    $data_to_be_cached = $exampleObject->exampleMethod();
    //then serialize and save it
    Mage::app()->getCache()->save(serialize($data_to_be_cached), $cacheId, array($cacheTag));
}
```

as explained [here](https://magently.com/blog/custom-cache-in-magento/).

How can one handle checking, saving and loading cache inside a custom module in Magento 2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As describe in the related post, you can inject your custom cache type : `Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache\Type` and use it.

```
public function __construct(\Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache\Type $cacheType)
{
    $this->_cacheType = $cacheType;
}

// Custom code Inside your function

$this->_cacheType->save(serialize($cacheData), $cacheKey, [\Vendor\Cachetype\Model\Cache\Type::CACHE_TAG], 86400);

$this->_cacheType->load($cacheKey);

$this->_cacheType->test($cacheKey);
```

Common methods :

- **load**
- **save**
- **test**
- **remove**
- **clean**

All methods can be retrieved here : `vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php`

Parent class :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Cache frontend decorator that attaches no additional responsibility to a decorated instance.
 * To be used as an ancestor for concrete decorators to conveniently override only methods of interest.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator;

class Bare implements \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface
{
    /**
     * Cache frontend instance to delegate actual cache operations to
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface
     */
    private $_frontend;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend)
    {
        $this->_frontend = $frontend;
    }

    /**
     * Set frontend
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function setFrontend(\Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $frontend)
    {
        $this->_frontend = $frontend;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cache frontend instance being decorated
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface
     */
    protected function _getFrontend()
    {
        return $this->_frontend;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function test($identifier)
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->test($identifier);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load($identifier)
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->load($identifier);
    }

    /**
     * Enforce marking with a tag
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function save($data, $identifier, array $tags = [], $lifeTime = null)
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->save($data, $identifier, $tags, $lifeTime);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function remove($identifier)
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->remove($identifier);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function clean($mode = \Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, array $tags = [])
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->clean($mode, $tags);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBackend()
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->getBackend();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getLowLevelFrontend()
    {
        return $this->_getFrontend()->getLowLevelFrontend();
    }
}
```