# How to create custom cache and store/get something in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache

I want to store any dummy data in custom cache and get that data in my own custom cache.
I have followed [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150074/using-magento-2-custom-cache-in-custom-module) but not telling much explanation.

Answer (score 0):

***I suggest that you should download this extension :***

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-quick-flush-cache/